# How to increase font size/font family of NetBeans IDE? (not the text editor's font)

Tags: netbeans, fonts

I'm having a problem with NetBeans fonts on my computer which for some reason are getting distorted. I decided to open this question because all searches I made ended up on how to change the fonts of the text editor but not of the IDE itself. As you can see on this printscreen, it is kinda hard to read because of this missing parts of the characters. I was having exactly the same problem with burp suite then I increase the font-size (didn't found a option there to change font-family) and it solved a little bit. I think that if I change these configurations it will be easier for me to read. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution came from http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFontSize

There's 2 options to do:

1. Run netbeans with the additional `--fontsize X` parameter from the commandline
2. Edit the `netbeans.conf` file located in the `%NETBEANS_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY\etc` directory and at the part that says `netbeans_default_options=....` append `--fontsize X` (Be sure that the option `-J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware` is set to `true`. Netbeans will ignore the `--fontsize` instruction if is `false`).

This should change the default GTK font size. As noted in the link, it may not work in Gnome desktop environments because the font there is controlled by Gnome.

Answer (score 2):

The netbeans.conf file for 10.x seems to have a slightly different syntax than previous versions.

In 8.2, adding "--fontsize x" worked. I couldn't get it to work in 10.0.

But adding "--fontsize x" to the start cmd works fine and doesn't compromise the font crispness when using a HD screen.